# adding condition of a subprogram in a different subprogram? python

Tags: python

Im a beginner in python and ive been coding a piece where two players are asked to reach a certain number (25 in this case) and is asked to alternate between the two players. Ive put the player in a different subprogram and im alternating it in a different subprogram. Ive tried many ways but none seem to work.

```
def get_input_from_player(player):
    '''
    This is the same as get_input, except this time, the prompt includes which player
    is supposed to supply the input.
    :param player: The player, either 1 or 2
    :return: An integer, either 1,2 or 3
    '''
    '''
    Same as in d(), but this time, make sure that the user can't enter
    a number that would put the total over 25.
    :return: None
    '''
    a = True
    total = 0
    while a:
        ask_user = input ("Player " + str(player)  +" Enter a number (1, 2 or 3):")
        if ask_user == 1 or ask_user == 2 or ask_user == 3:
            print "valid input"

            total = ask_user + total

            if total < 25:

                print total
            else:
                a = False
        else:
            print "invalid input"

    print "----------------xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx---------------------"

    pass # REPLACE THIS WITH YOUR CODE

def f():
    '''
    Same as in e(), but ths time, print out which players move it is,
    on each turn. There are 2 players, Player 1 starts and they alternate.
    Hint: add a player variable, as well as use get_input_from_player(player)
    :return: None

    a = True
    total = 0
    team1 = 1
    team2 = 2

    **'''
    playerOne = get_input_from_player(1)
    playerTwo= get_input_from_player(2)**
    #Here is where i have trouble with because it should alternate as soon        as one of the players get in invalid



    print "----------------xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx---------------------"


    pass # REPLACE THIS WITH YOUR CODE


# Remove the # in front of the function below to actually call it
'''
a()
b1(0)
b1(-5)
b1(15)
b2(0)
b2(-5)
b2(15)
get_input()
c()
d()
e()
'''
#get_input_from_player(1)
#get_input_from_player(2)
f()
#raceTo25()
#raceTo(25)
#raceTo(17)
#raceTo(100)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks suspiciously like a homework assignment.

I tried to understand what functionality you are looking for, but I may have missed something. My solution could certainly be improved upon, but I didn't want to change the arguments or return values of the functions.

In general you should avoid using non descriptive names like f and a.

```
total = 0

def get_input_from_player(player):
    while True:
        ask_user = input("Player " + str(player) + " Enter a number (1, 2 or 3):")
        if ask_user == 1 or ask_user == 2 or ask_user == 3:
            if 25 < ask_user + total:
                continue
            else:
                return ask_user
        else:
            print "invalid input"


def who_is_first_to_25():
    global total
    while True:
        playerOne = get_input_from_player(1)
        total += playerOne
        if 25 <= total:
            print "player 1 is first to 25"
            break
        playerTwo = get_input_from_player(2)
        total += playerTwo
        if 25 <= total:
            print "player 2 is first to 25"
            break
    total = 0
    print "----------------xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx---------------------"

who_is_first_to_25()
```

Comment: This was a test i was trying to do online and this is the resut ty, I understand how u did it while i tried to everything together